# Change specific hyperlink location

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a menu that has submenus that drop down on a hover, however I am making it responsive and I need it the submenus to drop on a click. **I have accomplished this** by targeting screensize.

**What i need to do is stop the anchor tag with the class of `stopLink` from executing on a click and just have the submenu drop instead of a page redirect**

**NOTE:** * you may ask why do you even need a hyperlink for the first element anyways, it is non-negotiable with my client

**HTML**

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
  <li>
     <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="/products.html" class="stopLink">Products</a>
     <ul class="subMenu>
        <li><a href="/product1.html">P1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/product2.html">P2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/product3.html">P3</a></li>
     </ul>
</ul>
```

**jquery - *works but blocks ALL LINKS***

```
  $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       location.href = "javascript:void(0);";
       $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
       return;
    });
```

**jquery - what i think needs to happen***

```
  $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().click(function (e) {
       $('.stopLink').each(function(e)
          e.preventDefault();
          location.href = "javascript:void(0);";
       });
       $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
    });
```

**Update**

Also tried to target it specifically based on browser size

```
var $w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;

if ($w < 1025) {
    $('.stopLink').each(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href = "javascript:void(0);";
    });
} else {
    $('.stopLink').each(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href = "/products.html";
    });
}

if ($w > 1025) {
    $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
    });
} else {
    $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().click(function (e) {
        $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
    });
}
```

thought the above code would work for sure but no dice :(

Comment: Does /products.html exist? You are changing the link to be only trigger but Search Engines will look for this link. If it does not exist this is bad practice.

Comment: yes it exists, however on a tablet that link just needs to activate the dropdown. the codes a bit more complex but i know this is where my error is and i tried to simplify the above example for simplicity

Comment: You need an ending quote mark for the class subMenu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$('.mainMenu > li.stopLink').unbind().click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   location.href = "javascript:void(0);";
   $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
   return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just use .click() and e.preventDefault() along with the check for the width of the screen you get this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clowkun/Md5qp/).

```
if(w < 1025) {
  $('a.stopLink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.subMenu').slideToggle(400);
    return;
  });
}
```